# Are there different kind of Manifests like the specific name AndroidManifest could suggest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I was wondering why `AndroidManifest.xml` is named like this and not simply `Manifest.xml` and if this means that there are different types of Manifests? I was reading the [information about AndroidManifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) but could not find anything. Or do they only want to emphasize that the coupling between the Manifest and Android (OS) is super tight?

Except for some included settings or icons which make a distinction about android built-in things and the option to include your own I have not seen Android name as a prefix except in the Manifest file. For example: the directories in the `res` folder have special meaning in android but also don't have the Android prefix or something alike, that makes me wonder even more why they decided to name it AndroidManifest instead of just Manifest.xml.

Comment: so what exactly you want to know

Comment: Well my question is two-folded. First I have a programming related question of: Can you write manifest like files yourself with a different name? I got this question because I don't see a point in having a Prefix to a file if the prefix is not used as a way to mark a distinction. It almost seems by the way they named it that there could be other Manifests as well. Second if it's not possible to create your own Manifests like files I wonder why it was named this way. Since they don't name the other directories with Android-prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there are different types of Manifests?

There are many things in Java development that are manifests, such as `WEB.XML` in a Java servlet, JAR manifests, etc.

> Can you write manifest like files yourself with a different name?

You are welcome to write your own framework that has its own manifest-style file structure for whatever purposes you want.

> It almost seems by the way they named it that there could be other Manifests as well.

Not in Android. However, Android is not the only framework in existence, either.

> Second if it's not possible to create your own Manifests like files I wonder why it was named this way.

Historical reasons, most likely. The name choice was made close to a decade ago. If you own a time machine, hop back in time, figure out where Android Inc. was based, head over there, and ask them.

On the whole, Google (let alone the old Android Inc. firm they bought) has not provided much in the way of detail about why things are named the way that they are.

Answer (score -2):

Every android app has just single AndroidManifeset.xml file. As for why this specific name was chosen, I have no idea, but if you look at it the name kind of makes sense.